# How to add more value options in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just started with coding again. And it's just a prove of concept. This code is working!

But I wanna add extra values, and have no idea how to do it. So that if you press one answer you can get multiple values. So for the first question I'm not only wanna be able to be a cat. But also a fish. But how do I do this?

HTML

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

## What animal are you? Take the quiz!

```
<form id="personalityQuiz">
    <h3> What is your favorite food?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="food" value="cat"> I only eat meat.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="food" value="horse">  I'm a strict vegetarian.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="food" value="dog">  I love all food!<br>

    <h3> What is your favorite hobby?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="hobby" value="horse"> I was born to run.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="hobby" value="dog">  Anything with a ball.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="hobby" value="cat">  Naps<br>

    <h3> What scares you?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="fear" value="dog"> Vacuum cleaners.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fear" value="cat">  Water<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fear" value="horse">  Anything that moves!<br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<div class="result" id="cat">
    <h2> You are a cat! </h2>
</div>
<div class="result" id="dog">
    <h2> You are a dog! </h2>
</div>
<div class="result" id="horse">
    <h2> You are a horse! </h2>
</div>
<div class="result" id="fish">
    <h2> You are a fish! </h2>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='file:///Users/Desktop/index.js'></script>
```

JS

```
$("#personalityQuiz").submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var answers = $(this).serializeArray();
    var scores = {
        cat: 0,
        dog: 0,
        fish: 0,
        horse: 0
    };
    for(var answer of answers) {
        scores[answer.value] += 1;
    }

    var maxAnimal = "cat";
    for(var animal in scores){
        if(scores[animal] > scores[maxAnimal]){
            maxAnimal=animal;
        }
    }

    $("#personalityQuiz").css ('display','none');
    $(".result#"+maxAnimal).css ('display','block');    

});
```

Comment: On which answer you what to show Fish?

Comment: Doesn't really because it's just a prove of concept. I just want to be able that if I add on the first to questions the answer fish. The end result is fish.

Comment: Everybody thanks for the answers! I'm looking into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my idea -

You need to define your question and answers lookup like

```
var qalookup= { "cat" : ['cat','fish'],"dog" : ["dog"], "horse": ["horse"] };
```

based on above object if cat is the answer then show all element based on the key.

Not perfect but should give you idea

```js
$("#personalityQuiz").submit(function(event) {

 var qalookup = { "cat" : ['cat','fish'],"dog" : ["dog"], "horse": ["hores"] };
    event.preventDefault();

    var answers = $(this).serializeArray();
    var scores = {
        cat: 0,
        dog: 0,
        fish: 0,
        horse: 0
    };
    $(".result").hide();
    
    for(var answer of answers) {
     var ans = qalookup[answer.value];
      ans.forEach(function(val) {
       $("#"+val).show();
        scores[val] += 1;
        });
    }

    var maxAnimal = "cat";
    for(var animal in scores){
        if(scores[animal] > scores[maxAnimal]){
            maxAnimal=animal;
        }
    }

    $("#personalityQuiz").css ('display','none');
    $(".result#"+maxAnimal).css ('display','block');    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="personalityQuiz">
    <h3> What is your favorite food?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="food" value="cat"> I only eat meat.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="food" value="horse">  I'm a strict vegetarian.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="food" value="dog">  I love all food!<br>

    <h3> What is your favorite hobby?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="hobby" value="horse"> I was born to run.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="hobby" value="dog">  Anything with a ball.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="hobby" value="cat">  Naps<br>

    <h3> What scares you?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="fear" value="dog"> Vacuum cleaners.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fear" value="cat">  Water<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fear" value="horse">  Anything that moves!<br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<div class="result" id="cat">
    <h2> You are a cat! </h2>
</div>
<div class="result" id="dog">
    <h2> You are a dog! </h2>
</div>
<div class="result" id="horse">
    <h2> You are a horse! </h2>
</div>
<div class="result" id="fish">
    <h2> You are a fish! </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set Javascript array or object as a value. E.G

`<input type="radio" name="food" value="{'firstValue':'cat','secondValue':'dog'}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to first hide *all* `.result` items before you show the one with the best score.
NB: you can use jQuery `hide` and `show` methods:

```
$("#personalityQuiz").hide(); 
$(".result").hide(); // <---- add this
$(".result#"+maxAnimal).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

(**I misread the question**, but will leave this not fully relevant answer in case it stirs other ideas for you)

Where you want multiple options, use checkboxes for these, instead of radio buttons.

Look at this tutorial:
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-get-the-values-of-selected-checkboxes-in-a-group-using-jquery.php

The idea is that you set the same name on multiple checkboxes (instead of radio buttons), and then just use JQuery to retrieve all the selected items into an array, like so:

```js
var animals = [];
$.each($("input[name='animal']:checked"), function(){            
    animals.push($(this).val());
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want one radio option to provide multiple values, simply add a value that separates multiple values with a separator like a comma:

```html
<input type="radio" name="food" value="cat,lion,tiger"> I only eat meat.<br>
```

Then, in your JavaScript, simply separate these with a simple stringValue.split( ',' ) which will give you the list of values that your single selection represents.

```js
var valuesOfSingleSelection = stringValue.split( ',' );
```

**If you want to get more elaborate**
You can also create a lookup table, where certain values can be mapped to more values, like so:

```js
var optionsLookup = {
  "cat" : [ "cat", "tiger", "lion" ],
  "dog" : [ "dog", "wolf" ],
  // etc.
};
```

This way, you could manage the data of your survey in a better way, without having to go back to HTML.